# First time equilibrium notation was used

Tags: notation, chemistry, thermodynamics

I was wondering when was the first time that a chemist wrote a chemical equilibrium with the $\rightleftharpoons$ symbol. And if it was before or after Arrhenius's dissociation theory.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_equilibrium#cite_note-5

Comment: @user6530 that looks like an answer to me.